# Regex for a string containing parenthesis in java

Tags: java, regex

I need a Regex to filter declaration of variables phrases.
I need the phrases which contains `int` or `char` which is not a function call.

```
int a;
char b;
int func(int a);
```

The result should match `int a` and `char b` but not int func(int a).
I did something like

> [ int | char ] \s* [ a-zA-Z_ ] [ a-zA-Z_0-9 ] * [ ?!\\(.*\\) ]

which is not working proper.
Thanks.

Comment: "**something like**"? Well what _did_ you do?

Comment: `double x; //Boy, am I glad I refactored from int a;`

Comment: The whole approach breaks down with something like `char a, *b, c[20];`. Also, there could be modifiers like `auto`, `register`, `extern` or `static` (assuming you are parsing C code).

Comment: Also, always test against something like `"/* this used to be\nchar a;\n*/"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try maybe this way

```
"(int|char)\\s+[a-zA-Z_]\\w*\\s*(?=[;=])"
```

- `(int|char)` means `int` or `char`, your version `[int|char]` means one of `i`, `n`, `t`, `|`, `c`, `h`, `a`, `r` characters
- `\\s+` one or more spaces
- `[a-zA-Z_]` one of a-Z letters or `_`
- `\\w*` zero or more of `[a-zA-Z_0-9]` which means a-Z letters, `_` or digits
- `\\s*` optional spaces
- `(?=[;=])` test if there is `;` or `=` after it (this part wont be included in match)

It will work for data like

```
int a;
char b = 'c';
int func(int a);
```

and will find `int a` and `char b`

Demo

```
//lets read data from file
String data=new Scanner(new File("input.txt")).useDelimiter("\\Z").next();

//now lets check how regex will work
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(int|char)\\s+[a-zA-Z_]\\w*\\s*(?=[;=])");
Matcher m = p.matcher(data);
while(m.find()){
    System.out.println(m.group());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try following regular expression:

```
(?:int|char)\s+\w+\s*(?=;)
```

Answer (score 1):

This regex

```
(int|char)\s+\w+\s*;
```

will match what you need ("the phrases which contains int or char which is not a function call"), even if "weird" spacing is used. In

```
int      a       ;
char  b;
int func(int a);
```

it matches the two first lines (exactly as they are).

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

```
(int|char)\s*\w+\b(?!\s*\()
```

Comment: yields `'int a', 'char b', 'int func'`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    String a="char a";
    Pattern p= Pattern.compile("(int|char)\\s*\\w+(?![^\\(;]*\\))");
    Matcher m=p.matcher(a);
    if (m.find()){
        System.out.println(m.group(0));
    }
```